# What has been observed as the "Hawking radiation" emitted by a black hole analog?

Tags: condensed-matter, black-holes, experimental-physics, hawking-radiation, bose-einstein-condensate

I've noticed [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.6550) which explains that they have observed the "Hawking radiation" emitted by a black hole analog. In which sense the Bose-Einstein condensate described by the paper can be considered a black hole analog? It is essentialy that the "analog of an event horizon" for sound waves is created or are there other relevant aspects? And what has been observed which mimics Hawking radiation? Is there something in this experimental observation that can only be explained by quantum effects, such as phonons?

Comment: Not trying to answer the question, but for comparison, a similar experiment is described [here by Unruh](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6612)

Answer (score 2):

All it means is that the mathematics governing both the BEC and BH are similar. So if the BH math predicts Hawking radiation it should come as no surprise that an analog is seen in BECs. It says nothing about what might really happen in a BH.

Comment: The analog uses phonons.  Light is so vastly greater in scope than sound that analogies between them seem kind of shaky, to say the least.